# TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote the following program for the school where I need help.
I can't find the error:

---

> ````
> Breier\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"
> "C:\Users\Max Breier\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\JaR\master.py" 
> pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2) Hello from the pygame
> community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html Traceback (most
> recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Max
> Breier\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\JaR\master.py", line 321, in
> <module>
>     main()   File "C:\Users\Max Breier\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\JaR\master.py", line 74, in main
>     Level1.Make_Tileset(IMAGE_LIBRARY)   File "C:\Users\Max Breier\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\JaR\Terrain.py", line 28, in
> Make_Tileset
>     for TILE in range(Chipset_Length - 1): TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>
> Process finished with exit code 1 ```
> ````

Here is my code:

```
def Make_Tileset(self, IMAGE_LIBRARY):
   Chipset_Length = self.Chipset.get_width() / 32
   for TILE in range(Chipset_Length - 1):
      self.TILE_DICT['Element_%s' % TILE] = self.Chipset.subsurface(32 * TILE, 0, 32, 32).convert_alpha()
      self.TILE_DICT['Element_%s_fill' % TILE] = self.Chipset.subsurface(32 * TILE, 32, 32, 32).convert()
   self.TILE_DICT['No_Element'] = IMAGE_LIBRARY['empty']

   for Surface in self.TILE_DICT:
      self.TILE_DICT[Surface] = pygame.transform.scale(self.TILE_DICT[Surface], self.SIZE_ON_SCREEN)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Chipset_Length` is used as an argument in the `rangle` function and needs to be an integral value. Therefore, you have to use the `//` (floor division) operator instead of the `/`  (division) operator to calculate the value:

<s>`Chipset_Length = self.Chipset.get_width() / 32`</s>

```py
Chipset_Length = self.Chipset.get_width() // 32
```